# Merging errors into my custom account_form is causing errors when properties don't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple account_form.rb model that I use for users who register:

```
class AccountForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor :company_name, :email, :password
  validates_presence_of :company_name, :email, :password  
end
```

Upon form submission I then use the values email, password, company_name to create other models like account, user, etc.  I have this all in a transaction.

Now when there are validation errors in these other models, I am trying to merge them into the account_form model but I get an error when the model props are not the same:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for #<AccountForm:0x00007fbfb9bae5c0>):
```

For example I am merging like this when validation fails:

```
@account.errors.each { |err| @account_form.errors.add(*err) }
```

Is there a way to pass down these errors to the view even though they don't exist in the account_form model?

I am displaying the errors like:

```
   <ul>  
     <% @account_form.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>  
     <% end %> 
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code does not work as expected is because it expects `@accounts.errors.each` to pass attribute/message pairs to the given block. However, only the attribute name is being passed, *not* the message. In your case `err` is assigned the value `:name` rather than something like `[:name, "is invalid"]`.

Iterate over the error entries instead:

```
@account.errors.entries.each { |err| @account_form.errors.add(*err) }
```

Aside: Consider the UX in this case. The user will likely be confused to see errors on fields which are not shown on the form.